# typescript: getting a string union value at runtime

Tags: typescript, enums, material-ui

Question 1:

I'm using a component library, material-ui, that provides interfaces and types for overriding the css class values for each component.

For the Select component, they export a type as a union of string literals

```
type SelectClassKey = "root" | "select" | "filled" | "outlined" | "selectMenu" | "disabled" | "icon" | "iconOpen" | "iconFilled" | "iconOutlined"
```

I'm creating a form to allow users to override each of these values themselves to be injected into the active theme.

I want to be able to iterate across this list to create the form without retyping these all out as an enum I can use at runtime.

Is there a way to access each of these elements at runtime or to create an enum whose keys are dynamically populated by the type's string union?

Question 2:

In addition, I want to create new types dynamically. Currently I'm able to use

```
type SelectOverride = {
  [key in SelectClassKey]?: string;
};
```

for creating the override objects.

I want to create a generic function to create these types from the SelectClassKey as a parameter, so something like

```
function makeOverrideType<T extends string>(arg:T): T {
  type newType = {
    [key in typeof arg]: string
  };
  return newType;
}

type SelectOverride2 = makeOverrideType(SelectClassKey);
```

But this isn't allowed, it seems I'm misunderstanding some elements of how typescript works.

Answer (score 3):

You can do neither of the things you want to do.

The best way to understand this is to write this code into the typescript playground and see the resulting javascript.

You will see that a type definition or an interface is only used at compile time, and does not exist at runtime.

To have a 'dynamic type' in the compiled javascript does not make sense, because the javascript does not have any types at all, beyond the basic types like `string` or `object`.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBcE8AcFNQCawGYEsB2ryoPboHSgDCOAttKgDawDOEOo6O4AFhgOYBQUcoAyrGoBjcEUoBDGjQDSsSKAC8oAEQAnHM2WgAPipqDYIrbuVpK1BMZU4AruEoZYlnXoMiAsrHQ2ryhKhpxACMLX1QhPDCI9AB5OHQovAAxKlCXZXC8GLsHdCdlTm4YeAFhcBiAN1hVVVQkRVAAb05QVtAAbQBrOVAMfjdRCSlZSABdAH4ALlAacFr0LgBfAG5CzhBQABEUDA5QCvFKG1pCABUWWngI8ip4cBx1sAArcQOaIVrocBm5jjocVSgHBBJ6GcA0TjRWYzSalMFiSQyHpKUypfKrSF4aHgWEDSrVWr1JTNNoqMyhabKC7mHDKAA0LTayls9kclkpAHcAZRLJwVoVwO0aKMGqYNEFxKplBigA